# jquery.validate v. 1.9 ignores some hidden inputs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

with version 1.7 everything works ok, all hidden inputs get validated,
but **with version 1.9 some do and some don't**
I use asp.net mvc 3 and jquery.validate + jquery.unobtrusive (jquery 1.7.1)

this is the generated html:

```
    <!--this gets validated-->
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Chef must be a number." data-val-required="The Chef field is required." value="" name="Chef" id="Chef">    
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Chef" class="field-validation-valid"></span>

    <!--this one is ignored-->
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MyFruit must be a number." data-val-required="The MyFruit field is required." value="" name="MyFruit" id="MyFruit">
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="MyFruit" class="field-validation-valid"></span>
```

anybody knows why could this happen ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With 1.9 version validation plugin ignores `:hidden` elements by [default](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/).

> Another change should make the setup of forms with hidden elements
>   easier, these are now ignored by default (option “ignore” has
>   “:hidden” now as default). In theory, this could break an existing
>   setup. In the unlikely case that it actually does, you can fix it by
>   setting the ignore-option to “[]” (square brackets without the
>   quotes).

Because you're using unobtrusive version, you can't set any option. So you don't init plugin yourself, therefor you have to change it's setting after it's initialized. You can fix it like this:

```
var validatorSettings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
validatorSettings.ignore = "";
```

This code works for first `form` element in the markup, you can specify your form(s) and change default behaviour.

Comment: Didn't you get this backwards in your code example?  _"square brackets **without** the quotes"_

Comment: the first input gets validated even though it's hidden

Comment: How exactly does that clear anything up?  The documentation specifically says to use **square brackets without quotes**, `[]`.  Yet instead, you're using quotes without square brackets `""`.

Comment: @Sparky672 with `""` it worked (for one more input, not all), with `[]` it didn't, @Emre Erkan, what should I do to set this settings to all forms not just to first one ?

Comment: apparently some hidden disabled inputs also don't get validated (some do), this rule can't be cleared

Comment: @Chuck, I'm not claiming it will work or not, otherwise I'd post it as my own answer.  However, [the official documentation](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/) is pretty clear when it says to use _"brackets **without** quotes"_; so I'm simply wondering if Emre can explain why he's leaving out the brackets and replacing them with quotes.

Comment: @Sparky672 probably he knows that the way it says doesn't work

Comment: @ChuckNorris Validation plugin won't validate `submit`, `reset`, `image` and `disabled` inputs. You can check it's [source](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js); `Line 454` and `Line 455`.

Comment: @Sparky672 I used it that way before and it worked well. `[]` or `""` I checked the code, it's using `.not()` method for excluding those elements, so it's no problem `[]` or `""`.