# ASP.NET MVC VALIDATOR: Form.valid() is always false using with validator ignore

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I have a dynamic input field in my form separated from the div tag. The active div input field is using **display:block** and the others inactive div is **display:none**. So, I searched a lot of possible solutions on how to validate the hidden div with the input fields. I found the validator ignore [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565135/jquery-validate-v-1-9-ignores-some-hidden-inputs). Here's the code

```
var validatorSettings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
validatorSettings.ignore = "";
```

The all hidden or display:none can validate also but when I try to put some valid form the result is always false. Here's the code:

```
if (!myForm.valid()) {
    console.log(myForm.valid());              
    return;
}
```

I trying to solve this issue almost 2 days. I can't solve this issue. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered my issue. Instead of using the display:none, I use visibility:hidden